# Modbus Slave Device Failure Exception Code (04)

Tags: modbus

I am trying to setup a communication (PC as RTU Master) with a heating system (Slave). Purpose is to be able to read some holding registers. However I am getting the Exception code 4 as a respons. 
My question is what would be the possible reasons for this? I mean is it possible that I am making an error in register value/offset/... ? I do not find a lot of information on this type of error.

Data send:   10-03-9C-4B-00-02-99-0C

```
"10" = Slave Address

"03" = Function Code

"9C4B" = Holding register 40011

"0002" = number of registers requested

"0C" = checksum
```

Data received: 10-83-04-10-F6

```
"10" = slave address

"83" = function code with highest bit set = exception

"04" = exception code
```

I am trying to read a 32bit float.

Thx

Comment: Could you add some more information to your question - such as the holding register number and data type?

Comment: updated request with extra info on holding register number and data type.

Comment: It looks correct. You are also getting a response back from the device, which means that the slave address is correct too. Maybe it is a problem with the holding register address. What brand and model is the heating system?

Comment: Most probably it wil be fixed, apparently always check if you don't need to write a '1' to a certain register before you can start reading :-) I can only check it next week...